# Subclassing Error: adding prototype methods does not take effect

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have made a error class hierarchy, starting with a BaseError class that is purely meant for subclassing. I have set the prototype using `Object.create(Error.prototype)` and I am rewriting the stack using the name of the current subclass. The name is set in a method called `configure` that needs to be implemented by the subclasses.

The problem is that although I explicitly add the `configure` method to the prototype of BaseError it is not actually accessible in the prototype chain.

[image: Failing]

I think it is somehow related to the `__proto__` instance property vs the `prototype` attribute.

[image: __proto__]

This is the code (transpiled from the Typescript definition)

```
var BaseError = (function () {
    function BaseError(msg) {
        var err = Error.apply(null, arguments);
        this.message = err.message;

        this.configure();

        if (err.stack) {
            this.stack = rewriteStack(err.stack, this.name);
        }

        if (typeof this.name === 'undefined')
            throw new NotImplementedError('must set "name" property in the configure call');
    }

    return BaseError;
})();

Framework.BaseError = BaseError;

// weird stuff need to happen to make BaseError pass an "instanceof Error"
BaseError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);

BaseError.prototype.configure = function () {
    throw new NotImplementedError(+' This method must be implemented in the overriding class!');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `Object.create(BaseError)`, not `Object.create(BaseError.prototype)` as you should.

Comment: Jeebus. Not the first time I have done something like that, either. Thanks. I see someone giving me a close vote. What do you think? Keep it up or not?

Comment: It was mine :-) I'm glad I could help, but I don't think the question will be helpful to others.